# Shape of the region in region monitoring iOS

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager

Is it possible to `startRegionMonitoring` for a polygonal region. The input to this method is a `CLRegion` and `CLRegion` only has one initialization method to define a circular region `initCircularRegionWithCenter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLRegion can only be defined as a circle. So not possible atm.

Comment: for iOS7, is there any changes? to support circle only is not useful since the regions are polygon in most cases.

Comment: Any updates since 2018 ?  Bueller?!?   Seriously not available via iOS yet...??!!